# Convert nvarchar(50) to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a table called `mt`, how do I convert the `Sun` column to date format from `nvarchar(50)`?

```
Sun
------------------------
Sunday, March 24, 2019
```

I tried the below query but it errored out.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,Sun,109) FROM [mt]
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
select convert(date, stuff(sun, 1, charindex(',', Sun) + 1, ''))
```